# can't compile RMarkdown pdf with image in child .Rmd - LaTeX Error - image file not found

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, tex-live

I'm compiling a pdf using child .Rmd's. The `example_child.Rmd` calls an image using `knitr::include_graphics()` and compiles fine on its own, but trying to compile `example_main.Rmd` produces the following error.

```
TeX Live 2019 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
! LaTeX Error: File `images/example_image' not found.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile example_main.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See example_main.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

**`example_main.Rmd` compiles fine when only calling child documents that don't call images (it calls data from sub-folders just fine). Any help would be appreciated! All the relevant info about my session and files is below:**

My working directory is `"/Users/example_project"`

The `example_main.Rmd` (file path `"/Users/example_project/folder_1/example_main.Rmd"`) YAML and code-chunk are as follows:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r child = './folder_2/example_child.Rmd'}
```
````

The `example_child.Rmd` (file path `"/Users/example_project/folder_1/folder_2/example_child.Rmd"`) YAML and code chunk are as follows:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r example, echo = FALSE, out.width='80%', out.height='50%'}
knitr::include_graphics("./images/example_image.png")
```
````

The full image file path is `"/Users/example_project/folder_1/folder_2/images/example_image.png"`.

My session info is as follows:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6, RStudio 1.2.5033

Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3 digest_0.6.25   evaluate_0.14   glue_1.4.0      graphics_3.6.3  grDevices_3.6.3 highr_0.8      
  htmltools_0.4.0 jsonlite_1.6.1  knitr_1.28.2    magrittr_1.5    markdown_1.1    methods_3.6.3   mime_0.9       
  Rcpp_1.0.4      rlang_0.4.5     rmarkdown_2.1   stats_3.6.3     stringi_1.4.6   stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.21.1 
  tools_3.6.3     utils_3.6.3     xfun_0.12       yaml_2.2.1     

Pandoc version: 2.3.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reconstruct the path to the image using the working directory of the child document   (in `example_child.Rmd`)

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r example, echo = FALSE, out.width='80%', out.height='50%'}
knitr::include_graphics(paste0(getwd(), "/images/example_image.png"))
```
````

It seem that this is an issue with 'grandchild' documents similar to that described [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1434) and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/143)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately this just produced a different error: ``! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.72 ...ct/folder_1/folder_2/images/example_image}

Try to find the following text in example_main.Rmd:
  ...ct/folder_1/folder_2/images/example_image} 

You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r ` in example_main.Rmd (see the above hint). See https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385 for more info.
Error: LaTeX failed to compile example_main.tex. `` The referenced issue about inline code doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: @kgf, can you compile the child doc with the new code? please double check that there are no excessive whitespaces

Comment: Yes, the child doc compiles fine with the new code. The error is only when knitting `example_main.Rmd`

Comment: @kgf The new error tells about inline R expressions, do you have `example_main.Rmd` exactly as in the question? Can you compile main doc if you exclude the image from the child doc and include in it just `getwd()`?

Comment: I think I discovered the issue - similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155042/knitrinclude-graphics-in-bookdown-is-not-rendering-the-image). My full working directory includes a folder called "Box Sync" and the whitespace is causing issues. Other Box users have [noted this problem](https://community.box.com/t5/Archive-Forum/Changing-the-default-name-of-Box-Sync-Folder/td-p/42855), but unfortunately Box doesn't allow users to change the default folder name! However, by removing `latex_engine: xelatex` from the  `example_main.Rmd` YAML, it compiles fine using your fix. Thanks!